# How to get ADDSDeployment module on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

I wonder to use AD DS Demployment CMDLets (`Install-ADDSDomain`, etc.) on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

I have installed **AD-Domain-Services** feature and in the list of available modules (`Get-Module -ListAvailable`) I see only **Active Directory 1.0.0**. I have PSVersion = 5.0.10586.117.

Unfortunately, I couldnot find if there is a possbility to get ADDSDemployment on Windows Server 2008 R2 and how to intall it.

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Install-ADDSDomain` Powershell cmdLet is only available for OS versions 2012 R2 or later. 
See the Microsoft doc on passing an answer file to `DCPROMO` for automating the promo process on 2008. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732887.aspx

You can use the DCPROMO GUI to build the answer file. The last screen before the actual promo begins has the heading "Summary / Review you selections".  On that screen there is also a button labeled "Export Settings" which will write the answers to a file.